# Run UNIX command in ant script - build.xml

Tags: java, unix, ant

How to put this unix command in ant script?

```
jar -xvf test.ear out.war | jar -x ; cd directory ; jar -xvf ../out.war
```

Will this work?

```
<target name="unear">
    <echo>***Un-tarring***</echo>
    <exec executable="jar" outputproperty="noOfFiles">
         <arg value="-xvf" />
         <arg value="test.ear out.war" />
         <arg value="|" />
         <arg value="jar" />
         <arg value="-x" />
         <arg value=";" />
         <arg value="cd directory" />
         <arg value=";" />
         <arg value="jar" />
         <arg value="-xvf" />
         <arg value="../out.war" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: No. that won' work - the jar executable won't konw what to do with the | or anything after it.  You'll need to break out the unix command into a few unzip and jar tasks.

Answer (score 2):

wars, ears and jars are simply zip files.  you can use the [unzip](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html) task to crack it open.
You'll need to break up the unix command in your example into multiple tasks.

Comment: Hmm.. this is more of a comment.  I won't choose to downvote you for that, however :)

Answer (score 1):

Pipes are interpreted by the shell, so make the shell interpret those.  Say:

```
<exec executable="sh">
  <arg value="-c"/>
  <arg value="jar -xvf test.ear out.war | jar -x ; cd directory ; jar -xvf ../out.war"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: sh will only be available on unix-like machines, which the OP is indeed using... but it's never the path to introduce platform dependencies in the build of a platform independent language.

Answer (score 0):

May be You can do something like this, just to ensure you are running unix commands on Unix OS & you can run any set of unix commands by wrapping inside a script :

```
<condition property="is.unix">
       <os family="unix"/>
</condition>

<if>
    <istrue value="${is.unix}"/>
<then>

<chmod file="${script.locater.path}/your_script.ksh" perm="755"/>
<exec executable="${script.locater.path}/your_script.ksh"
  dir="${from.dir.you.want.to.execute}">
</exec>
```