# How to find SVN latest tag name using Ant

Tags: svn, ant

I want to find the svn latest tag name using Ant.

This is how the svn repo structure looks

//svn/tag/project/tag-1

//svn/tag/project/tag-2

//svn/tag/project/tag-3

//svn/tag/project/tag-4

//svn/tag/project/tag-5

In the above case the latest tag name is "tag-5". i want to know the the latest tag is tag-5 in ant so i can check out for my build. can someone please help. thank you in advance.

Comment: may be you can give it a try with something like this: svn ls -r 'HEAD' {svn-repo-url}/tags | head -1

Comment: I want it to be done using ant. Is it possible to do ls within ant script?

Comment: well, you can wrap any set of commands in a script & use ant's exec task . Eg answer I added you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898323/run-unix-command-in-ant-script-build-xml/18910064#18910064